# Parcel v2.8.3 doesn't build properly

Tags: javascript, parcel

Whenever I run parcel build index.html, it builds everything allegedly, however launching the project from the dist folder I come to realize none of the actual JS has been bundled. The HTML and CSS are properly bundled and the page shows both its styling and its markup, however the page functions as if there is absolutely no Javascript written. And I am just stuck at that, until I run parcel index.html. Then the app is ran and its working just fine, however I get extra files in my dist folder and the index.html file changes its script src. I am clueless what I should try to do. Any suggestions are appreciated. Dont know what exactly I need to attach to make this easier for anyone trying to help out. Thanks

I expected the bundler to be complete, I have tried updating parcel and adding "default": "index.html", to my package.json file with no luck.

Comment: Have you followed [_"Building a web app with Parcel"_](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/)?

Comment: Ive looked at the documentation of course, however I cannot find a fix to my issue.

Comment: Share some code so we can help you find the culprit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am actually clueless which part of the code might cause such an issue. However if it is of any help I can attach the github repo of the project before I tried all the fixes that failed. Please checkout the Inital commit as the following commits are a mess. I have tried the fixes using the state of the Initial commit. https://github.com/MrWalt/forkify

Answer (score 0):

Place your `index.html` in `src/` and set `source` in your `package.json` to `src/index.html`.

```json
{
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `type` of your script to `module` in your `<head>`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I just followed the linked startup docs and mine built with the latest (same) version of Parcel.

Comment: I tried this just now, unfortunately nothing changed. And the type of my script has been set to module since Ive began building this app. I appreciate your suggestions though.